# How do I create a box upon a button press

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to make it so that whenever I press a button a box appears with text in it.
HTML where the box should appear when created.

```
<div class="trades">
</div>

<button onclick="create()">add</button>
```

Javascript function for creating it

```
function create() {
    var box = document.createElement("div");
    creation.setAttribute('class', 'itembox');
    creation.setAttribute('id', 'itemBox');
    var holder = document.createElement("p");
    holder.setAttribute('id', 'output');
    var item = document.createTextNode("testing");
    holder.appendChild(item);
    box.appendChild(holder);
    var mainholder = document.getElementByClassName("trades");
}
```

CSS to make a box

```
.itembox {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: consider accepting answers that answer you question by clicking the grey tick icon next to the best answer

Answer (score 4):

With some minor modifications you are there:

```js
function create() {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.setAttribute('class', 'itembox')
  var holder = document.createElement("p");
  holder.setAttribute('class', 'output');
  // You can set the inner text of the p tag without creating a text node.
  holder.innerText = "The text in the box"
  box.appendChild(holder);
  // Trades should be an element with and ID because you probably only ever want to insert into one place.
  var trades = document.getElementById("trades");
  trades.appendChild(box);
}
```

```css
.itembox {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="trades">
  </div>

  <button onclick="create()">add</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function create() {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.setAttribute('class', 'itembox');
  box.setAttribute('id', 'itemBox');
  var holder = document.createElement("p");
  holder.setAttribute('id', 'output');
  var item = document.createTextNode("testing");
  holder.appendChild(item);
  box.appendChild(holder);
  var mainholder = document.getElementsByClassName("trades")[0];
  mainholder.appendChild(box);
}
```

```css
.itembox {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="trades">
</div>

<button onclick="create()">add</button>
```